# OpenCV: memory location issue

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, memory, pdb-files

I just installed opencv 2.4.10. I use the free version of visual studio. 
It compiles opencv commands and I was able to present my computer camera input on a window.
However, it seems that any attempt to access the values in the Mat object fails. If I start with (for example):

```
Mat M;
M.create(4, 4, CV_8UC(2));
```

I can see that M is not empty but:

```
double b = M.at<double>(0, 0);
```

results in:
Unhandled exception at 0x75C92F71 in myOpenCVStudy.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x006AECD4.

```
int a = countNonZero(M);
```

results in:
Unhandled exception at 0x75C92F71 in myOpenCVStudy.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00ADF868.

and:

```
cout << "M = " << endl << " " << M << endl << endl;
```

results in:
Unhandled exception at 0x734ADE19 (msvcp100.dll) in myOpenCVStudy.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

For the second case I get a "No Symbols Loaded". Something about C:\Windows\SysWoW64\KernelBase.dll. Saying I need to change PDB and binary search paths (Microsoft Symbol Servers), how it is done.

Would appreciate your help,

Thanks,

Yair

Answer (score 1):

When you created your `Mat`, you specify the type as two channels of 8-bit unsigned data by passing `CV_8UC(2)` to the `create` function:

```
M.create(4, 4, CV_8UC(2));
```

Attempting to access 8 bytes by casting to `double` *will* cause problems:

```
double b = M.at<double>(0, 0);
```

So, you need to access using an appropriate structure like [`Vec2b`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec), which contains two 8-bit bytes:

```
Vec2b b = M.at<Vec2b>(0, 0);
```

Now you can access the values from each of the two channels:

```
unsigned char uCH1 = b[0];
unsigned char uCH2 = b[1];
```

The reason that `countNonZero` crashes is probably because [according to the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#countnonzero), it is expecting a single-channel input, not a two-channel input. Running in Debug mode should have resulted in an appropriate assertion.

If you really *do* want a single-channel image of doubles, just change the type to `CV_64F` when you create it:

```
Mat M;
M.create(4, 4, CV_64F);

double b = M.at<double>(0, 0);

int a = countNonZero(M);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image has two channels, use cv::Vec2b instead of double

```
cv::Mat M;
M.create(4, 4, CV_8UC(2));
...
cv::Vec2b b = M.at<cv::Vec2b>(0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Indeed the code you send me works. However, I still don't understand why is it, when I copy examples from the opencv tutorials, release 2.4.9.0, like:

Comment: The return type of `at<>()` function depends on the number of channels used. e.g. `cv::Mat` object contains uchar elements in case of grayscale images, and vectors in case of multichannels. So for multichannel images the columns contain as many sub columns as the number of channels. In your example `M` has two channels (`CV_8UC(2)` means 8 bit unsigned and 2 channels) that's why you need `cv::Vec2b`. If you have a BGR images then `cv::Vec3b` will be the appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the mat this way:

```
cv::Mat M = cv::Mat(2,2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255));
```